# Play framework 2.0 deployment steps (I think something is missing)

Tags: deployment, playframework-2.0, production

I have some strange problems when I deploy application build with Play framework 2.0. It looks like deployment didn't clean/overwrite compiled files. This I know because one method is changed but still the old is somehow called...

My deployment steps:

1. in app directory `../play stop`
2. upload all files to app directory from development (except application.conf)
3. `../play clean compile stage`
4. in target directory: `./start -Dhttp.port=80 &`

I need some "best practices" advices ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tips:

- Try to use `play clean-all` instead `play clean`.
- Use the GIT for controlling changes, maybe you forgot to upload something.
- Use [alternative configuration file](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ProductionConfiguration) for running app in different environments.
- Use [`dist`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ProductionDist) command for building independent production versions, with some `bash scripts` + `git hooks` + `load balancer` you'll be able to switch versions without stopping the application. Anyway remember to move and unzip created file outside the `/dist` directory, as it is cleaned every time when you call `play dist` command.

Comment: I think `clean-all` made it.